# Check existence of an isomorphism in four examples

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Check if there exists an isomorphism for :
$$ i) \ G = (\mathbb{Z}_{15}, +_{15}), \ H = (\mathbb{Z}_{15}, +_{15}), \ f(1) = 2 $$
$$ ii) \ G = (\mathbb{Z}_{15}, +_{15}), \ H = (\mathbb{Z}_{15}, +_{15}), \ f(1) = 3 $$
$$ iii) \ G = (\mathbb{Z}_6, +_6), \ H = S_3 $$
$$ iv) \ G = (\mathbb{R}, +), \ H = (\mathbb{Z}, +) $$
where $$ f: G \rightarrow H $$

Problem: 
I know that I should firstly check conditions for homomorphism and this part I can, but I don't know how I have to check surjection and injection. Could you help me ;) ?

Comment: Which of the examples have you checked the existence of a (non-trivial) homomorphism for? Have you ruled any of the answers out?

Comment: Do you know a condition equivalent to injectivity regarding the kernel of a homomorphism? Do you know the first isomorphism theorem? It could be helpful.

Comment: @DevlinMallory just already check i) - it can't be, because $$ f(14 +_{15} 1) = f(0) = 2 != 0 $$ (must exist e), example ii) is correct, but I have problem with iii), because I don't know how I should start check homomorphism could you give me hint?

Comment: Your check for part (i) doesn't make any sense to me. Take a look at my answer below and see if it helps you.

Comment: I would double check your reasoning for i) and ii); I'm not sure what you mean by $f(0)=2!=0$, but an isomorphism should exist in i) and not ii). Otherwise, Cameron Buie gives a great answer below

Comment: @Devlin: Why, thank you!

Comment: Yes, my fault i) is correct, but ii) is bad ;) I'm reading answer @CameronBuie now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the first three parts, $1$ generates $G,$ so given any $h\in H,$ there is a unique homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $f(1)=h,$ given by $$f(\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1+_{15}\cdots+_{15}1}})=\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{h+_{15}\cdots+_{15}h}}.$$ (This is a nice exercise.) Hence, there's no need to confirm that $f$ is a homomorphism in the first two cases. Among finite sets of the same size, functions are injective if and only if they are surjective, so you need only check one of those in each the first two cases (I recommend injectivity, personally.)

For the third part, think about what you know about $G$ and $H.$ Do you know anything different about them that would make an isomorphism impossible? If not, I recommend that you figure out what the homomorphisms $G\to H$ are, and see if any are injective/surjective (remember, we only need to choose where to send $1,$ and the homomorphism is completely determined).

For the fourth part, think about what you know about $G$ and $H.$ Do you know anything different about them that would make an isomorphism impossible? Specifically, what do you know about the relative sizes of the two sets in question?

Comment: Ok, I read your answer and I check the homomorphism for i) and ii) your method and it's good solution but I don't know how I should check injectivity, because I've never check before. Could you show me for i) ?

Comment: You need to show that if $f(x)=f(y),$ then $x=y.$ Alternately, show that if $x\ne y,$ then $f(x)\ne f(y)$. Before I show you, I note that you mentioned above that $f$ is *not* a homomorphism in the second case. How did you determine that?

Comment: Yes, again my fault I didn't write number 15, and this was a bug ;) I checked again and i) and ii) is correct. Your method is awesome!

Comment: Do you know what the kernel of a homomorphism is? If so, what are some things you know about it?

Comment: I heard about this, but I've never used in a practial.

Comment: Okay, then. Surjectivity might be easier for you to show for the first part. You need to take an arbitrary $h\in H$ and show that there is some $g\in G$ such that $f(g)=h$. You may need to take care of the cases where $h$ odd, $h$ even separately. For the second part, can you think of any non-zero $g\in G$ such that $f(g)=0$? What can you conclude from that?

Comment: I'm getting ready to sit down for dinner, so I will be away from my computer for a little while. See what you can do, and I'll try to answer any additional questions when I get back.

Comment: Do feel free to *ask* any questions you have if you get stuck, but be aware that I won't be getting back to you immediately.

Comment: Bon appetit, but I must found a formula for i) ? So I think, that shoud be $$ f(x) = 2x (mod 15) $$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: And know I read about surjective and we have $$ f: \mathbb{aZ}_{15} \rightarrow \mathbb{bZ}_{15} $$, and we should use every elements from bZ, right? But we used only $$ 0, \ 3 \ 6 \ 9 \ 12 $$ So i) isn't surjective function ?

Comment: And the same situation is for example ii) ? I think so. Because $$ \mathbb{Z}_{15} = \{0, \ 1, \, ..., \ 14 \} $$ If my comments are true, how I should proof this, because I can't find a counterexample. Maybe write all possibles and it will be the counterexample?

Comment: @Mat: Do you know that the kernel of homomorphism $f$, defined as $f^{-1}(\{0\}),$ is trivial if and only if $f$ is injective? This is very helpful and applied quite often.

Comment: @StefanH. My last post is wrong? It's mean that i) is surjective? Could you tell me more about $$ f^{−1}(\{0\}) $$

Comment: @Mat: I didn't mean to say anything about your post. I just wanted to tell you this property.

Comment: Ok, I founded in my notebook this property, but could you show me, how I must find kernel in homomorphism?

Comment: @Mat: You can apply it in i) for example. If $f(x)=2x\mod15$, how do find the kernel? It contains all elements $x$ in $\Bbb Z_{15}$ such that $f(x)=0$, that means $2x$ is divisible by $15$. Can you show that this set is trivial (equal to $\{0\}$)? That would prove the injectivity.

Comment: I found definition: $$ ker \ f = \{ g \in G \ : \ f(g) = e_H \} $$ Element who give us element 0 is only 15, so 0? Of course this for i).

Comment: For example ii) we get $$ \{f(5) = 0, \ \ f(10) = 0, \ \ f(0) = 0 \}$$ so this isn't injectivite?

Comment: @Mat: Your note about the range of $f$ being $\{0,3,6,9,12\}$ is correct, but **not** for the first part. Rather, that is true for the *second* part. Stefan's hint is a good one. That's a great way to show that the homomorphism from the first part is injective.

Comment: So my conclusion is not correct? 1) Injective consider good? 2) What is wrong with surjective.

Comment: Ok, if you can answer to my questions in post above. I must go to sleep, because in my country is 3 a.m., if you also show me how I must prove iii) homomorphism. Good night :-).

Comment: In the first part, it is an isomorphism. In the second part, it is not, because it is not surjective (also not injective). For the third part, note that there are only 6 homomorphisms $G\to H,$ so unless you can see a reason why they shouldn't be isomorphic, then I recommend that you simply figure out what they are, using the same method I mentioned previously. If any of them is surjective, then you've got your isomorphism. Otherwise, there is no isomorphism.

Comment: So can you show me, how I must understand surjective? Because for me both i) and ii) isn't surjective.

Comment: @Mat: For the second part, the range of $f$ is $\{0,3,6,9,12\},$ and the kernel of $f$ is $\{0,5,10\}.$ Since the range of $f$ isn't all of $H,$ then $f$ isn't surjective. Since the kernel isn't just the zero element, then $f$ isn't injective.

Comment: @Mat: For the first part, it may seem that $f$ isn't surjective, but remember that $f(x)=2x\pmod{15},$ so that $f(8)=16=1,$ for example. It's also not too difficult to show that the kernel of $f$ is $\{0\},$ so that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Ok, but could you show formal proof ? For surjective?

Comment: @Mat: Honestly, the injectivity proof (showing that $0$ is the only element of the kernel of $f$) is probably easier. Care to take a crack at it while I write up a couple of surjectivity proofs?

Comment: @Mat: **Proof 1**: Take any $y\in H$. We must show that there is some $x\in G$ such that $y=2x\pmod{15}$. Since $1=16=2\cdot 8\pmod{15},$ then letting $x=8y\pmod{15},$ we have $2x=2\cdot8y=y\pmod{15},$ as desired. // **Proof 2**: Take $y\in H.$ If $y=0,2,4,6,8,10,12,$ or $14,$ then $y$ is already in the form $2x,$ and we're done. Otherwise, $y=y+15\pmod{15},$ so $y=16,18,20,22,24,26,$ or $28,$ and once again, we're done. //

Comment: But I must show surjective and injective, right? I think, that not enough prove injective, because I don't know what is with surjective.

Comment: When $G$ and $H$ are finite and of the same size, then $f:G\to H$ will be injective **if and only if** it is surjective (as I remarked in my answer), so for the first three parts, you need only deal with injectivity or surjectivity (whichever's easiest), but there is no need to deal with both.

Comment: Ok, thank you so for i) condiser injective, if is ok, surjective also ok, ii) injective wrong, surjective also wrong?

Comment: @Mat: Here's a third surjectivity proof. Let $\operatorname{im}(f)$ denote the range of $f$. Then (proceeding *modulo* 15), $$\begin{align}\operatorname{im}(f) &= \{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28\}\\ &= \{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,1,3,5,7,9,11,13\}\\ &= H,\end{align}$$ so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @Mat: Exactly so. Have you made any progress on the third or fourth part?

Comment: I understand just i) and ii). How I should check homomorphism in iii) ? $$ Z_6 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \} \ \ \ S_3 = \{id, {1 2 3 \choose 2 1 3}, ... \} $$ I can't see, how I join permutation with normal number?

Comment: @Mat: Well, as I said, there are 6 such homomorphisms. For each $h\in S_3,$ there is a homomorphism given by $$f(\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1+_6\cdots+_61}}) =\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{h \circ\cdots\circ h}},$$ where $\circ$ is the operation on $S_3.$

Comment: Can you illustrate me how i should regard on this h? Because I haven't f(1) and I'm starting now with permutation.

Comment: And in four part isn't homomorphism? Because for example $$ f(x) = x^3 \ \ \ f(\sqrt{2}) = 2\sqrt{2} != \mathbb{Z} $$ We can't find good formula, because for x we can set anything.

Comment: @Mat: True, in the third part, we aren't *given* a homomorphism. As I said, though, there are only six such homomorphisms to check, since there are only six choices for what $f(1)$ can be. Note that we'll always have $f(0)=id,$ regardless of our choice of $h$ to be $f(1)$. In the $h=id$ case, we have $f(1)=id,$ so we can rule that one out, since it isn't injective. In the $h=\binom{1\:2\:3}{2\:1\:3}$ case, we have $$f(1)=\binom{1\:2\:3}{2\:1\:3},$$ $$f(2)=\binom{1\:2\:3}{2\:1\:3}\circ\binom{1\:2\:3}{2\:1\:3}=id,$$ so again, it isn't injective. We can readily check them all this way.

Comment: @CameronBuie "True, in the third part" or four? Becoure I wrote about four example ;)

Comment: @Mat: An easier way to do this is to prove that if $G$ is a cyclic group and $f:G\to H$ is an isomorphism of groups, then $H$ is a cyclic group. Then all you have to do is note that $S_3$ is not cyclic, while $\Bbb Z_6$ is, so no isomorphism can exist between them.

Comment: @Mat: As for the fourth part, there are several ways you can do it, but the approach will be very different, since we're now dealing with two infinite groups. Do you know anything about the relative sizes of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: No I have no idea about relative sizes of R and Z. So for third example I must check f(2) = id, f(3) = id, ... , f(5) = id ? If we can't get id, so it isn't homomorphism ?

Comment: @Mat: Let me reiterate once again. For the third part, there are $6$ different homomorphisms to check, one for each $h\in S_3,$ given by $$f_h(\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1+_6\cdots+_61}}) =\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{h \circ\cdots\circ h}}.$$ **You do not need to check that this is a homomorphism**. You need to check if any of them are injective (or surjective, if you prefer, since it is the same thing in this case). If any of them is injective (surjective), then it is an isomorphism. If none are, then there are no isomorphisms....

Comment: Since you don't know about the relative sizes of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z,$ then we'll need to get a bit clever. Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z$ is an isomorphism. Then $g=f^{-1}:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R$ is **also** an isomorphism. (If you didn't know this, prove in general that an isomorphism's inverse is an isomorphism.) Show that for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ we have $g(n)=n\cdot g(1).$ Then, show that $g$ cannot be surjective--that is, show that there is some $y\in\Bbb R$ that isn't of the form $n\cdot g(1)$--so that $g$ is **not** an isomorphism, a contradiction. Thus, there is no isomorphism $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z$.

Comment: ok, now i get it, and if I want show injective for third, I must check f(3) = h o h = id, etc. If is id, so isn't injective? Sorry that I ask about it, but I just start with permutations.

Comment: @CameronBuie I understand your proof for iv) part, but how I should proof g(n) = n * g(1) ?

Comment: @Mat: For the third part, that's absolutely right. If there's **any** non-zero $x\in\Bbb Z_6$ such that $f(x)=id,$ then $f$ is not injective. As for the fourth part, I'd start by showing it is true for all non-negative $n.$ (**Hint**: induction, using the fact that $g$ is a homomorphism.) Then use the fact that $$0=g(0)=g(n+(-n))=g(n)+g(-n)$$ to show that it holds for the negative integers.

Comment: We want show $$ g(n) = n * g(1) $$ We start from base case: $$ n = 1 $$ $$ g(1) = 1 * g(1) \Rightarrow g(1) = g(1) \Rightarrow Left = Right \ \ \ OK $$ Next let $$ n = k \ \ \Rightarrow g(k) = k * g(1) $$ is true. Next step, we show $$ n = k + 1 $$ Let's start: $$ g(k + 1) = (k + 1) * g(1) \ \ \Rightarrow g(k + 1) = k * g(1) + g(1) $$ And it's true, because we let n = k. Proof is ok?

Comment: It's not bad. A bit cumbersome.

Comment: So what I need add?

Comment: And what kind of method I should show that g cannot be surjective?

Comment: @Mat: You can connect the work done on both sides by $$\begin{align}g(k+1) &= g(k)+g(1)\\ &= k\cdot g(1)+ g(1)\\ &= (k+1)\cdot g(1).\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok, but how I proof surjective, because I can't see this.

Comment: I already told you how to show that $g$ is not surjective. Do you know anything about the real numbers that might assist in that task?

Comment: so I must use $$ g(k + 1) = g(k) + g(1) = ... $$

Comment: form: $ n \cdot g(1) $ ?

Comment: @Mat: You must show that there is some $y\in\Bbb R$ that is **not** of the form $n\cdot g(1).$

Comment: $ y \in \mathbb{Z} $ there exists some $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ $ f(x) = x * g(1) \ \Rightarrow x = \frac{y}{g(1)} $ $$ f(\frac{y}{g(1)}) = \frac{y}{g(1)} * g(1) = y $$ So I guess, I proof is not correct, because I get, that surjective exist, it's weird.

Comment: @Mat: How about $y=\frac12 g(1)$?

Comment: Yes, but I tried prove this, and could you point my fault? Because I don't see it.

Comment: @Mat: Explaining the various things that are incorrect in your proof would be getting a bit far afield. Rather, I will suggest that you put $y=\frac12g(1).$ Show that $y\in\Bbb R,$ and that $g(n)\neq y$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z.$ Thus, $g$ is not surjective.

Comment: Ok, I understand :), so I's over?

Comment: @Mat: Yes, that takes care of everything here.